# Is it possible to build a tree report by using congos8?

Tags: tree, cognos-8

I am using cognos 8.4.1 professional report studio, and want to build a tree report to represent CAD bom, but don't know how, anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to be working off a dimensional data model and have a decent knowledge of the differences in syntax between relational and dimensional data within Report Studio.

If you just have relational data you can mock it up in Framework Manager using DMR to make it look like a hierarchy.

[This is an OK starting guide](http://cognosandme.blogspot.com/2010/08/tree-prompts-explained.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help.In my understanding, the component of tree prompt is used for parameter   inputting, not a report result. And what is DMR?

Comment: DMR = dimensionally modeled relational [data]. In Framework Manager, you can mock up relational data (say from SQL Server or similar) into hierarchies so you can have a true multi-level tree prompt without using Transformer, TM1, or another true cube source.

Comment: In my understanding, tree prompt is a parameter input component,not a report result.And CAD BOM I will represent is a tree, you can't tell how deep the hierarchies,so I don't know how to prepare my data model.

Comment: Tree prompt is indeed just a special prompt which represent hierarchal data to allow the user to choose from different levels. Read your initial post wrong. The term tree report isnt tossed around much. You're going to have to devise a solution using dimensional data represented in list form. Perhaps with grouping and dynamic column selection. But really this seems like a much more complex question and it might be prudent to explain your data and ultimate goal more, with pictures if possible.